# Is a layover of 1 hour 30 mins enough at IAD (Washington Dulles) given it's the port of entry and immigration will be required?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, short-connections, missed-flights, iad

I have an Indian Passport, and I am traveling FRA-IAD-BUF (Frankfurt-Washington(Dulles)-Buffalo. I have a single Lufthansa ticket, however the connecting flight from Washington to Buffalo is United Airlines.

Given that Washington is the port of entry, will 1 hour 30 mins be sufficient to catch the onward flight?

Do I need to re-checkin the baggage(for customs)? Or will it be forwarded to Buffalo?

What happens if I miss it? Will Lufthansa schedule me on the next flight?

Also, given the baggage allowance of 23*2 for international, if a new flight is booked from Washington to Buffalo, will I be able to carry it?

Comment: I would tend to say no; on international arrivals, I always give myself at least four hours. You never know what will happen at customs/baggage claim.

Comment: IAD is one of the worst airports when it comes to customs and immigrations..

Comment: @pnuts *[Citation needed]*

Comment: The first port of entry requires you to collect your bag, go through customs, recheck your bag, go through security again and get to your flight. So my advise is Tell the agent when checking in your bag in Frankfurt, it's in their best interest to get you to make the flight so they may put your bags as priority. And tell the flight attendants, they usually are nice and help people with short connections get off first. Other than that don't take any food, even the stuff that is allowed will get you more scrutiny which eats time.

Comment: @pnuts If the layover in question is on a *domestic* flight at the airline's own terminal, then yes, you can trust them. But if you have to cross international borders, change airlines, or collect luggage for any reason, no, you cannot trust the airline not to strand your ass. Once, I let an airline's website plan a trip for me through LAX. They gave me a 36-minute layover there. Seasoned travelers through LAX know to leave at least a couple hours there because that airport is terrible at baggage handling. **In short**: no, the airline's booking site cannot be trusted. You have to be smart.

Comment: @pnuts Awesome! I'm glad you've had some great experiences flying internationally. I have, unfortunately, had numerous bad experiences with U.S. carriers when flying internationally. I've completely written them all off for anything but domestic travel. So I guess it comes down to which airline you are travelling with as much as which airport you are travelling through.

Comment: So I went ahead with the above itinerary and made it comfortably to the connecting flight. Although with reasonable 'quantum of luck'. :) 
The arriving flight was 15 minutes early and the following immigrations took a little less than an hour. However, customs and re checking was a breeze. The security check took another half an hour and thankfully the connecting flight was in the same terminal. After a long walk, I made it with about 5 minutes left for the boarding to commence. 
However, I would avoid making such tight travel plan in the future and avoid all the anxiety. Phew.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IAD is indeed a dreadful airport. A new train system has very slightly improved matters. From the exit past customs to the furthest gate at remote terminals can take 20 minutes easily. You will miss your connection if (a) your incoming flight is late, (b) the Border entry officer hassles you, (c) your luggage, which I believe you will have to re-check, is slow. For international flights, the luggage at least is not usually a problem. However, you *will* make your flight with a reasonable quantum of luck. Although the computer should know, tell the customer service personnel that you are transferring: they may hold the Buffalo flight a few minutes.

Now, yes, if you are on a continuous ticket, Lufthansa will be responsible for rebooking you. Unfortunately, I only see one non-stop a day IAD-BUF, so you will end up on some circuitous route. Check the schedule for your flight day to know what options to ask them to rebook on.

Comment: Agreed. I've laid over for 23 hours in LAX for missing a once-a-day flight due to weather.